# Invoking runtests through TortoiseSVN client side hook script for pre-commit

Tags: perl, tortoisesvn

Using tortoiseSVN client side hook script for pre-commit, we are trying to run some unit test cases using Test::Harness's runtests sub. 
In TortoiseSVN's Setting->Hook Scripts->Configure Hook Scripts (for pre-commit), I provide a batch file name against the "Command Line to Execute:" heading.

This batch file contains, the following line
run.pl unittest.t

run.pl contents

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::Harness;

# Run a single test suite
my @files = @ARGV;
runtests(@files);
```

So, when I try to commit any code, this script get invoked and failed with the following error message:

```
Could not execute (D:\Perl589\bin\perl.exe -w D:\t\unittest.t): open3: Can't call method "close" on an undefined value at D:/Perl589/lib/IPC/Open3.pm line 368.
```

Any idea how can we resolve this issue.

Comment: the error happens in D:/Perl589/lib/IPC/Open3.pm at line 368. Find out why your script fails there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your Windows computer know what to do with scripts that ends in `*.pl`? That is, if you double click on a `.pl` file, does it run Perl? This is set in the registry. You set this up under the *File Types* tab in the `Folder Options`. In older version of Windows, this could be done via the *Tools->Folder Options...* menu. I'm not sure where this can be done in Vista and Windows 7.

Once you have the relationship between Perl and the `*.pl` files setup, you also have to edit your `%PATHEXT%` environment variable to include `.PL` in the list of suffixes that are considered executables.

Otherwise, you simply have to put the name of the Perl interpreter in your Batch file's hook script:

```
 C:\Perl\bin\perl run.pl unittest.t
```

One more possibility is to use the [pl2bat](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/perl5.004_04/win32/bin/pl2bat.pl) script that came with your Perl installation that turns Perl scripts into Batch files.

Comment: @rpg What happens when you try to run the `D:\Perl589...` command from the command line?

Comment: sorry for a late reply. it seems that run.pl open a IPC to STDOUT and it's failing. This is what I came to know though perlmonks.